# Cocoa Pods Not Installing Dependencies for Firebase (Not creating the .xcworkspace file)

Tags: cocoapods

Good day everyone,

I am new to app development and I was trying to install Firebase Authentication for an app I am building.

I have installed xcode 11.6 and downloaded cocoa pods text file via the command prompt (sudo gem install cocoapods)to my project file.

I then edited the textFile with the Firebase dependencies (libraries) and used the following command:

pods init
then:
pods install

**it returned the following error:**

admins-MBP-2:Clean Wheels lyndon$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies

――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

#### Command

```
/usr/local/bin/pod install
```

#### Report

- What did you do?
- What did you expect to happen?
- What happened instead?

#### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.9.3
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]
    RubyGems : 3.0.3
        Host : Mac OS X 10.15.6 (19G73)
       Xcode : 11.6 (11E708)
         Git : git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
```

#### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.4
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.1.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.5.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0
```

#### Podfile

```rb
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Clean Wheels' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Clean Wheels

  # add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics

    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'  
  
  # add pods for any other desired Firebase products

  # https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods

end
```

#### Error

```
JSON::ParserError - 416: unexpected token at '{
      "dependencies": {
        "Firebase/CoreOnly": [

        ],
        "FirebaseD'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/json.rb:61:in `from_json'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:742:in `from_string'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:716:in `from_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:186:in `specification'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver/lazy_specification.rb:37:in `specification'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver/lazy_specification.rb:29:in `subspec_by_name'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:362:in `block in specifications_for_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:362:in `map'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:362:in `specifications_for_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:165:in `search_for'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:274:in `block in sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_by'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:53:in `block in sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:70:in `with_no_such_dependency_error_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:52:in `sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:288:in `initial_state'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:210:in `start_resolution'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:168:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1065:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1063:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:410:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:235:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:234:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:156:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=416%3A+unexpected+token+at+%27%7B%0A++++++%22dependencies%22%3A+%7B%0A++++++++%22Firebase%2FCoreOnly%22%3A+%5B%0A%0A++++++++%5D%2C%0A++++++++%22FirebaseD%27&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...

- Pod Headers Referenced by :path Not Updated
  https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2329 [closed] [1 comment]
  08 Sep 2014
- Crash when doing pod lib create without Demo project
  https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2337 [closed] [5 comments]
  08 Sep 2014
- pod lib create: why am I forced to use testing framework? Why also no XCTest?
  https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2338 [closed] [1 comment]
  26 Jul 2014

and 9828 more at:
[https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/search?q=416%3A%20unexpected%20token%20at%20%27%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22dependencies%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Firebase%2FCoreOnly%22%3A%20%5B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22FirebaseD%27&type=Issues&utf8=✓](https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/search?q=416%3A%20unexpected%20token%20at%20%27%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22dependencies%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Firebase%2FCoreOnly%22%3A%20%5B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22FirebaseD%27&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `13.6` on target `Clean Wheels` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This looks like a corrupt CocoaPods cache:

```
pod cache clean --all
sudo rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos
```

Details at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9672#issuecomment-632810885

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for responding. I read and implemented the suggestions in the link you gave but uninstalling cocoapods, re-installing it again, cleaning the cache, removing the repos then finally running the pod install again still produced the same error. Please help me through this I am desperate to solve this problem. The cocoapods version I have is 1.9.3 which seems to be the latest.

Comment: To add additional information: The folders are created but theres no files added.

Comment: I've got good news IT WORKED! I ran the two commands you gave in the wrong directory. It needs to be run in the root directory and then cd (project directory) use pod init again and then pod install. Thanks Paul!