# Firestore/Firebase not working when installing on cocapods package manager

Tags: json, swift, ruby, cocoapods

**When I am installing Firestore by using the command pod 'Firebase/Firebase' in my pod file, I keep on getting JSON parse error. Here are the contents of my pod file:**

```
platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'Flash Chat iOS13' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Flash Chat iOS13
    pod 'CLTypingLabel', '~> 0.4.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
    
    
end
```

**Here is the error I am getting:**

```
Analyzing dependencies
```

――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

#### Command

```
/usr/local/bin/pod install
```

#### Report

- What did you do?
- What did you expect to happen?
- What happened instead?

#### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.10.0
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]
    RubyGems : 3.2.3
        Host : macOS 11.0.1 (20B29)
       Xcode : 12.2 (12B45b)
         Git : git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
```

#### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.4
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.1.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.5.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0
```

#### Podfile

```rb
platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'Flash Chat iOS13' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Flash Chat iOS13
    pod 'CLTypingLabel', '~> 0.4.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
    
    
end
```

#### Error

```
JSON::ParserError - 416: unexpected token at '"src/core/lib/http/httpcli'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/json.rb:61:in `from_json'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:742:in `from_string'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:716:in `from_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:186:in `specification'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/set.rb:58:in `block in specification_name'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/set.rb:56:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/set.rb:56:in `specification_name'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:216:in `search'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `block in search'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `select'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `search'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:416:in `create_set_from_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:385:in `find_cached_set'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:360:in `specifications_for_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:165:in `search_for'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:274:in `block in sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_by'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:53:in `block in sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:70:in `with_no_such_dependency_error_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:52:in `sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:754:in `push_state_for_requirements'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:746:in `require_nested_dependencies_for'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:729:in `activate_new_spec'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:686:in `attempt_to_activate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1074:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1072:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:414:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:239:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:238:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:160:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=416%3A+unexpected+token+at+%27%22src%2Fcore%2Flib%2Fhttp%2Fhttpcli%27&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
Found no similar issues. To create a new issue, please visit:
https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/issues/new

**I also tried the following debugging steps before posting this question:**

1. I followed the steps given in the stackoverflow discussion [Error Installing 'pod Firebase/Firestore' in my iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64591137/error-installing-pod-firebase-firestore-in-my-ios-app), but that did not work for me.
2. I also tried removing the pod cache and dependencies from the project, but it still did not work
3. I uninstalled and reinstalled cocoapods but the issues still persisted.
4. I also read that this issue can be an outdated version of pod. However, my current pod version is 1.10.0. I tried downgrading my pod version to 1.9.0 and it still did not work.

I was wondering what can my issue be here. I am debugging this issues from almost a day now, but I keep on getting the same error. Is there any other way I can fix this issue or can get a way around it?

Comment: might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63341913/cocoa-pods-not-installing-dependencies-for-firebase-not-creating-the-xcworkspa

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cocoa Pods Not Installing Dependencies for Firebase (Not creating the .xcworkspace file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63341913/cocoa-pods-not-installing-dependencies-for-firebase-not-creating-the-xcworkspa)

Comment: I agree: looks like a cocoapods cache issue

Comment: Adding sudo while removing the repos did work. Cant believe it was such an easy fix. Thank you for the help!